# Excel nested IF question for checking duplicates name in earlier columns

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

I would like to seek help on setting up a nested IF for my excel formulas.

This is the way my data is being entered by another colleague.
For example, on a daily basis, he records the type of fruit being delivered, and to which stall it was delivered (columns L to V).

This results in stall being mentioned twice or multiple times in each data row, which doesn't allow me to use my COUNTIF function as there are repeats.

However, I just need a formula to show me which stalls were delivered fruits (minus the stall name being mentioned twice as they received two different types of fruits). I wanted to set up 5 columns at the end of my table to do some nested IF functions.
Basically, columns X to AA would have formulas to identify if the store name in M,O,Q,S,U would be repeated.

Column Y = column O (if not identical to column M), if column O and Y were identical, reference column Q (if column Q is not equal to column O and Y), otherwise reference column S.

Basically, I should not have store names repeating in row display between column X to AB.

[image]

Comment: What about countifs()?

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: im on office365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created Tables and am using structured referencing, but you can change this to regular addressing if you wish:

With Excel O365 and the `UNIQUE` function:

```
X2: =UNIQUE(IF(INDEX(Table1[@],{2,4,6,8,10})="","",INDEX(Table1[@],{2,4,6,8,10})),TRUE)
```

and fill down.

[image]

Comment: Hi Ron, if there any possibility of preventing the blank cell from returning as a result?

Comment: @jade.elves I don't understand. What is the issue with the blank cells that I see in `Y2,Z2:AB4,AB5`?